# Is there anyway to specify the version of kernel update with apt-get? Debian 7

Tags: debian, apt, kernel

Is possible to select the version of Kernel I need in apt-get?
Actually, I need to update it but I had lot of configurations problems with 3.2.

Or the only way is compiling the kernel?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you check `apt-cache search linux-image` you can install one of those if the version matches what you need. Otherwise check backports, if they don't provide it either you'll need to compile.